# The event handler of an html button not fired when child element clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```html
<button id="emailbtn" class="cen-inline-block w3-button cen-bg-color-fade-min cen-padding-small w3-small cen-margin-left-small cen-align-top cen-round-top-right cen-hover-text-white-fade aim-trigger aim-datafill"  style="width:30px;height:30px"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

```js
//Note Assign function is called when DOM loads completely
function Assign(){
var element = document.getElementById('emailbtn');
//if addEventListiner is supported by the browser
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            
               element.addEventListener("click", rhandler,false);
              
           }
           //if attachEvent is supported
           else if (element.attachEvent) {
               element.attachEvent('onclick', rhandler);
           }
           else {
               //add to the element DOM property
               element['onclick'] = rhandler;
           }
}
```

I am trying to assign an event handler to the click event of a button using addEventListener.
When exactly the button is clicked, it fires the assigned event handler. But when any of the buttons child element (font awesome icon) is clicked the event handler is not fired (nothing happens) on chrome.

Please, I need any assistance on how I can make the event handler to fire when any part or child element of the button is clicked in chrome browser.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate... I just can't find it.

Comment: A click event is by default passed up the element tree, but without seeing your code we can't tell where the issue is.

Comment: I just edited the question (including code)

Answer (score 1):

Have been able to discover where the issue is coming from.
It is from the event listener function **rhandler**.

The listner uses attribute of the target element (button element), which i used ***e.target*** to get the element from the event.

In chrome e.target represent the clicked element (which could be the child element).
Changing **e.target** to **e.currentTarget** do the trick.